# Is there way to parse json data in python?

Tags: python, json, parsing

import json

f = open('C:\Users\Hello\Desktop\usecase2.json',encoding = 'utf-8')
data = json.load(f)

print(data)

-Raw Data sheet contains the raw data to be parsed and arrange as per "Desired Output" sheet
-The number of iteration data for each Pur Lot is not same, however it is required to capture the entire raw da -you have to create a JSON file to capture entire data of Raw Data with the key as Pur Lot.
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A08fY.png)

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM5bR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to convert JSON (essentially text) to a python dict , then I would suggest you use this:

**

```
import json
# some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)
# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"])
```

**

then you can call y['keys'] = values to use data
here , y['name'] = "John"